# Using Substring and like together

Tags: mysql

Hi I want to extract all values from the column Old_priceplan such that the outcome gives me 1 Mbps only
[image]

So if its xyz 20 Mbps it extracts 20 Mbps only and so and so forth.

also
is there a way i can use or in locate like locate('Mbps' or 'MB', old_priceplan?)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: update your question  add  a clear data sample and the expected  result as  tabular text  .. (not a image with a row .. where is not clear which result you expected )

Comment: substring(old_priceplan, locate('Mbps',old_priceplan) -  length(old_priceplan) - 4 , ifnull(locate('SL',old_priceplan),0) )

Comment: found the solution myswlf

Comment: is there a way i can use or in locate like locate('Mbps' or 'MB', old_priceplan?)

Answer (score 0):

You can build a proper like condition eg:

assuming you value  is  store in a var

```
set @str = '1 Mbps';
```

then

```
select  Old_priceplan 
from my_table  
where Old_priceplan  like concat('%', @str, '%')
```

And as suggested  by  Lutz be sure you have a proper sanitized  value assigned  to var

Comment: If you follow this suggestion, make _very_ sure that you know exactly what's in your `str` variable. Google "Little Bobby Tables" for more information.

Comment: @Lutz  correct answer  updated  with you suggestion

Answer (score 0):

substring(old_priceplan, locate('Mbps',old_priceplan) - length(old_priceplan) - 4 , ifnull(locate('SL',old_priceplan),0) )